# getJSON in phonegap application not working

Tags: json, web-services, jquery-mobile, web, cordova

I have looked through the older posts regarding this problem but did not find the solution to my problem.

I have 2 REST services on my computer, 1 for login and 2nd for sending a list items.

I am able to connect and login using the login webservice .
My second webservice is called after the login and it provides JSON data in following form..

[{"oid":101,"summary":"this is my first order"},{"oid":102,"summary":"this is second order"}]

I want to parse this JSON string and create a list of "oid" and then if I click on 1st item i should see the "summary" on a new page. When i hit the back button i want to call the service again so the list refreshes.

here is the code i tried.

```
<script>
    $.getJSON('http://192.168.2.36:8080/phoneservlet/getOrders', function(data){
            var output = '';


    $.each(data, function(index, value){

    //add each value to the output buffer (we also have access to the other properties of this object: id, start, and end)
    output += '<li>'+ value.oid +'</li>';
    });

    //now append the buffered output to the listview and either refresh the listview or create it (meaning have jQuery Mobile style the list)
    $('#your-orders').append(output).listview('refresh');//or if the listview has yet to be initialized, use `.trigger('create');` instead of `.listview('refresh');`
    });

    </script>
```

And this is the  for list

```
<div data-role="page" id="currentorders">
<div data-role="content" id="data">
<ul data-role="listview" id="your-orders" data-divider-theme="b" data-inset="true">List of Orders</ul>
</div>
```

The problem is that my list does not get populated. I see an empty List with just the title of my list which is "List of Orders"

I am new to jquery so i still have not figured out how i can show the summary on a new page..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) For first issue you need to check get json url

2) Second issue show the summary on a new page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="currentorders">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Orders</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
      <ul data-role="listview" id="your-orders" data-divider-theme="b" data-inset="true"></ul>
    </div>
</div> 
<div data-role="page" id="summary">
    <div data-role="header">
        <a href="" data-rel="back" id="back" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse">Back</a>
        <h1>Summary</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" id="content">         
    </div>
</div> 
</body>
<script>
$('#currentorders').live("pageshow", function(){
    // Here obj get using $.getJSON function, I have done direct using your json object only for example 
    var obj = [{"oid":101,"summary":"this is my first order"},{"oid":102,"summary":"this is second order"}];
    var list = "";
    $.each(obj, function(key, value){            
        list += '<li class="row"><a href=""  data-role="none" data-title="'+value.summary+'" data-transition="slide">'+value.oid+'</a></li>';
    })
    $('#your-orders').html(list).trigger('create');
    $('#your-orders').listview('refresh')
})

$('#currentorders li a').live("click",function(){
    var content = $(this).attr("data-title");
    $("#summary #content").html(content);
    $.mobile.changePage( "#summary", { transition: "slide", changeHash: false });
}) 

$('#summary #back').live("click",function(){
    $.mobile.changePage( "#currentorders", { transition: "slide", reverse: true, changeHash: false });
}) 
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you might missed the following access rule in config.xml file:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot connect to an IP address through a PhoneGap Application as these cannot be whitelisted, you can only make CORS requests to domains whitelisted in your config: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html